# I want to replace all of the things which are not black text and white background in an Image

Tags: python

I tried doing this but it takes too long to run. The problem is that the black text in the image is made by a lot of different shades of gray and the color. I also want to remove shades of gray that range between 230 to 255.
How can I do this better?

```
OLD_PATH = r'C:\Users\avivb\Desktop\Untitled.png'
NEW_PATH = r'C:\Users\avivb\Desktop\test.png'

R_OLD, G_OLD, B_OLD = (range(230,255), range(230,255), range(230,255))
R_NEW, G_NEW, B_NEW = (255, 255, 255)


from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(OLD_PATH)
pixels = im.load()

width, height = im.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r, g, b = pixels[x, y]
        for i in R_OLD:
            for j in G_OLD:
                for k in B_OLD:
                    if (r, g, b) == (i, j, k):
                        pixels[x, y] = (R_NEW, G_NEW, B_NEW)
im.save(NEW_PATH)
```

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote all working answers, and accept the one you like the most. Probably you know this, but this is to let the community know which answers were useful and to reward the people for their time and effort as well ;) See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for performance, I would avoid as many `for` statements as I can, as they are slower in `python` than in other low-level languages (like `C` or `C++`).

This is my approach using `openCV`, should be **very** fast:

```
import cv2 as cv
# Set range of color values
lower = np.array([230, 230, 230])
upper = np.array([255, 255, 255])
# Threshold the image to get only selected colors
mask = cv.inRange(img, lower, upper)
# Set the new value to the masked image
img[mask.astype(bool)] = 255
```

Please note that there are no explicit `for` in this code!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate over the old ranges like that - use an if on each channel and your speed will greatly improve.

```
threshold = 230
replacement_pixel = (255, 255, 255)

from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(OLD_PATH)
pixels = im.load()

width, height = im.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r, g, b = pixels[x, y]
            if r >= threshold and g >= threshold and b >= treshold:
                pixels[x, y] = replacement_pixel
im.save(NEW_PATH)
```